# how do i write a binary number to STM32 GPIO

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I want to control a 4 bit multiplexer with my nucleo board. I understand I have to write either to the higher or lower parts of the BSRR resgister, to set bits high and set bits low.

I want to increment some variable, say `multp_select` and then output it to GPIOA (in AVR I can do this just by writing `PORTA = multp_select` for example) what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the register ***`ODR`*** instead.

My advice is: read the Reference Manual - everything is described there.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been suggested, the ODR register is what you are looking for and can be found as GPIOX_ODR in the reference manual. You need to download it and read the GPIO section. To write to the GPIOA_ODR register, your code will end up looking like this

```
GPIOA->ODR = multp_select;
```